# Distance between a point and a nonconvex set

Tags: linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, non-convex-optimization

Is it possible to describe the distance between a point and a nonconvex set by the pointwise maximum of affine functions if my nonconvex set $\mathcal{O}$ is the union of halfspaces defined below: 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_j=\{y\mid a_j^\top y\geq b_j\},\; j=1,\dots,m,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}=\bigcup_{j=1}^{m} \mathcal{O}_j
\end{equation}
I was able to derive only the following equation, which is not what I want to have.
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{dist}(y,\mathcal{O})=\min_j\bigg\{\frac{(a_j^\top y-b_j)^{+}}{\|a_j\|}\bigg\}
\end{equation}

Comment: Is $a_i y$ the inner product and means the same as $a_j^\top y$?

Comment: Isn't $\mathcal{O}$ defined as an intersection of halfspaces (which are convex) and therefore convex again?

Comment: I'm sorry, just corrected the $a_j^\top y$. $\mathcal{O}$ is not the intersection of halfspaces, it is the union of the halfspaces.

Comment: The equation I'm afraid is wrong.
$$\text{dist}(y,\mathcal{O}_{j})=\frac{(b_{j}-a_{j}^{T}y)^{+}}{\|a_{j}\|}$$
as 
$$a_{j}^{T}(y+\frac{(b_{j}-a_{j}^{T}y)^{+}}{\|a_{j}\|}\frac{a_{j}}{\|a_{j}\|})=a_{j}^{T}y+(b_{j}-a_{j}^{T}y)^{+}=b_{j}.$$ What do you want to use it for? I might be able to make some usefull suggestions based on that.

Comment: I'm trying to create a convex optimization problem for collision avoidance.